# Why is not letting me enter a value to a char with scanf()?

Tags: c

Why is this not letting me enter a character into a variable inside a function. I have the exact same thing in another function and I have no problem with that one.

This is the one that works

```
char anotherOne='s';
while(anotherOne=='s'){
    printf("\nWould you like to continue?");
    scanf("%s", &anotherOne);
}
```

Then I have this one in another function that is the one that doesn't works

```
char op='s';
while(op=='s'){
    printf("next(s) o prev(a)?");
    scanf("%s", &op);
}
```

In the second one when I write a character and hit enter it just stop and exit the execution.

I have more code in between both examples but I tried wrote them just as shown and it happened the same thing.

Comment: Since `%s` writes at least two characters (a letter and a null byte, assuming you type a letter and return) into the space pointed at by `op` or `anotherOne`, you are invoking undefined behaviour and overwriting who knows what and generally you've got a good demonstration of why you need to avoid undefined behaviour (it doesn't have to be consistent because the behaviour is undefined).

Answer (score 2):

The format specifier `"%s"` expects a pointer to an array of characters, not the address of a single `char` - but since arrays decay to pointers when passed to a function, `scanf` doesn't know the difference and tries to write the entire string to `&anotherOne`, which is undefined behavior, since you don't know what in your process' or system's memory will be overwritten.

What you need to do is use the format specifier `"%c"` instead if you want to read a single character.